# How to find missing values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, recursion, group-by

I am trying to simplify a much more complicated business scenario - please bear with me!

I currently have a table like the one below.

[image: Example]

It shows a person, the type of test they are having (eye test, typing test), what year the test started, the year that the tests end and TestYear being an entry when a person completed the test.

What I need to do, is to find all of the years between the StartYear and EndYear that a person does not have a TestYear. For example:

[image]

Having played around with this, I have been able to get this working for just one Name/TestType, but I run into difficulty when I attempt to run this across an entire table with many different names and testTypes.

The below creates a table variable of what I currently have.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid any types of loop, but for the moment, any advice or feedback on how this could be achieved would be very much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Tests Table (Name varchar(200), testType varchar(200), StartYear int, EndYear int, CurrentYear int)

INSERT INTO @Tests (Name ,testType, StartYear, EndYear, CurrentYear)
values ('John', 'Eye',  2016,   2021,   2018)
,('John',   'Eye',  2016,   2021,   2019)
,('Barry',  'Typing',   2019,   2021,   2019)
,('John',   'Typing',   2019,   2021,   2019)
,('John',   'Typing',   2019,   2021,   2020)

select * from @Tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all possible years and then remove the ones that exist:

```
with years as (
      select distinct name, testtype, startyear as currentyear, endyear
      from tests t
      union all
      select name, testtype, currentyear + 1, endyear
      from years
      where currentyear < endyear
     )
select y.*
from years y left join
     tests t
     on t.name = y.name and t.testtype = y.testtype and
        t.currentyear = y.currentyear
where t.name is null;
```

I doubt that you will have more than 100 years for a given name/test.  But if you do, then you will need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa5c5a5c375b5a762baf29ae59d22daf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This query has a few errors in it. It will also generate multiple copies of the same row in the output where a user has multiple tests in a name/testtype pair which has missing tests.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your input.  I will transpose this to my larger problem and see if this can resolve the matter.  I really appreciate the advice :-)